# Conditional filtering on Count - Django

Tags: python, django, django-1.10, django-aggregation

I want to count a number of all incorrect choices in question.

I have a query for a number of all choices:

```
questions.annotate(choices_count=Count('choices'))
```

Now, when I want to filter incorrect choices only into the Count function, it returns:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'choice' into field.

```
questions.annotate(choices_count=Count(Case(When(choice__correct=False,then=1))))
```

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are writing 'choice' instead of 'choices' while checking it to False